# My Gamma automatically changes coming out of standby

Tags: laptop, graphics-card

I have the W520 Lenovo Laptop with the Color Calibrator (not sure if the software is the culprit). When I calibrate it using the color calibrator (Pantone XRite software) the color looks pretty great.

The issue is everytime I come out of standby the gamma goes to a super high value every time and everything is washed and I only have two ways to fix it

1. recalibrate
2. if I right click on the desktop and go to NVIDIA Settings > Display > Adjust desktop color settings

There is a tab that says

```
Choose how color is set
   - other applications control color settings
   - use nvidia settings
```

I set 'use nvidia settings' so everytime I come out of standby, the values here do not change but I know what is shown is not what is set so if I just move the "gamma" slider up then back down to the exact same value, the gamma is fixed on the screen and now is truly the value shown in the slider.

I don't know why my gamma keeps changing when I come out of standby but its extremely annoying and the calibration takes too much time for me to do it everytime. I need to find a solution!

Comment: Is the colour calibration correct when you restart the computer after it being set up correctly?

Comment: Same thing when I restart, calibration goes off again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `msconfig.exe` and disable the three Intel startup entries that say Common User Interface.

This should stop it from overriding gamma values.

<sub>I believe you are the same person who wrote [this Lenovo community post](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/W-Series-ThinkPad-Laptops/ThinkPad-W520-gamma-values-automatically-change-upon-resume-from/ta-p/478249).</sub>