# Colors appear washed out after coming out of sleep/booting/using 3d application

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

I'm seeing a similar problem to the one described in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/303615/my-gamma-automatically-changes-coming-out-of-standby), but my circumstances are a bit different, and the suggested solution doesn't apply (that is, those startup entries do not exist). I was previously using an Nvidia card on my desktop computer. When that failed (hardware issue), I was using my onboard graphics (Intel HD) for a while, until I could go pick up a new card. The new card is Nvidia as well. Now, every time I boot, wake the computer from sleep, or quit a game, the colors appear washed out.

The only way to fix this is to play with the "digital vibrance" slider in the Nvidia control panel. Playing with the gamma slider does nothing, but as long as I make any change at all to the digital vibrance slider and put it back to where it was (50%), the colors will return to normal.

I've tried uninstalling the Intel HD Graphics software already. What else could have been left behind, in either settings or drivers/services, that could be causing this issue?

EDIT:

Graphics card is GTX1060, monitor is Asus VX279.

Comment: Please specify your NVIDIA card and monitor. Try (1) The [Nvidia RGB Full/limited range toggler](http://blog.metaclassofnil.com/?p=83); create a system restore point first, just in case. (2) In the NVIDIA Control Panel => Change resolution => Select use NVIDIA Color Settings => Set "Output Dynamic Range" to "Full".

Comment: @harrymc Edited to provide the hardware info. Your fix seems to have worked, but I'm going to leave this open a couple days just to be sure. Can you turn it into an answer so I can award the bounty?

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of manipulations that may solve the problem :

- The
  [Nvidia RGB Full/limited range toggler](http://blog.metaclassofnil.com/?p=83)
  updates some registry items used by the NVIDIA driver.
  Create first a system restore point, just in case.
- In the NVIDIA Control Panel, under Display, go to **Change resolution**.
  Under **Apply the following settings**,
  select **Use NVIDIA Color Settings** and set **Output Dynamic Range** to **Full**.